# Simple product not map into the Configurable product after migrate data from 1.9.2.4 to 2.3.5-p1

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate data from 1.9.2.4 to 2.3.5-p1 with data-migration-tool but my configurable product didn't map with any simple product. How can i solve it???
[image]

[image]